# Understanding the formula of anisotropic filtering (Barcelos et al. (2003))

Tags: computer-vision

I am currently trying to understand a paper about shadow removal (DESHADOWING OF HIGH SPATIAL RESOLUTION IMAGERY APPLIED TO URBAN AREA DETECTION, Samara Azevedo et al.), but I am currently stuck at this formula:

[Equation about anisotropic filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiFdJ.png)

The text under the equation says:

where f^(t) corresponds to the scaled version of f, g = g(|∇ G_σ ∗ f^(t)|) represents an edge detection function, and G is the classic Gaussian kernel governed by a tuning parameter σ.

I am not sure if it is better suited at the StackOverflow site, as it is a computer vision related task, but if I am wrong just correct me. So now my questions:

1. Could somebody guess in which way f_(t) is scaled? As f_(t) - f doesn't make any sense if the images are not the same size.
2. Could somebody explain the ∇ to me? Usually, it denotes an edge detection algorithm (e.g. Laplacian), but as it is not described I am not 100% sure. Especially here: g = g(|∇ G_σ ∗ f^(t)|) I am not sure what the ∇ does, as calculating edges on a kernel is not useful (I think).

I know this is not a lot of information and i cannot post the paper here directly, but as the results of this paper look promising I would like to understand it, though it seems like there is some information missing (maybe the authors consider it common knowledge)

Thanks!

Comment: $\nabla$ is the gradient operator ... $\nabla = \hat{x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\hat{y}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\hat{z}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}+$